# Is there a Visual Studio plugin that prevents writing unmatched { and }

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins

Often while writing or editing C++ code in VS I end up messing up by not having matching braces `{` or `}`. So I was wondering is there a tool that prevents writing `{` in a sense that when you press { key it automagically generates

`{
}` 
and puts cursor between braces. Ofc one might want { in a string, so tool would have to allow that, also forcing closing of the string would be nice feature(I think Eclipse has it).

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) does this, but it's not free.

On the other hand, you can try to write a macro for it yourself. It's easy enough to write a macro, although it's very difficult to get near-100% accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) does this and a *lot* more useful things for C++ developers, but unfortunately it's not free.

However, there is a free Brace Completer extension written by Joel Spadin that does precisely this. [Download it here from the Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d/). It's an excellent product.

His description does mention that Microsoft's [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension now includes brace completion functionality, but that's a pretty heavy extension. Since I don't use or want most of those other features, I prefer to continue using Joel's one trick pony.

Also, it's never been clear to me from the description of PPT whether it works with C++ code. Most of the extensions focus on C# and VB.NET, which is nice as far as it goes, but doesn't help us C++ devs much. Joel's extension works great with C and C++.

Finally, never fear if you do accidentally mis-match a pair of braces. All versions of Visual Studio come with a handy tool that can catch mistakes like these. It's called the *compiler*. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A very very simple plug-in would be

When typing { directly type } then head back to fill in the scope.

Same goes for ( and )

Never a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper does this too, but again its not free.

Not sure if CodeRush Xpress does it, it probably does as it does similar stuff to ReSharper. There is a free version of that.

For more information on that look here:
[CodeRush Xpress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee663901.aspx)

Comment: Just noticed this was C++ and not C# so I am not sure if my answer is valid.